# Sorting elements based on file name length and integer sequences in QT C++

Tags: c++, qt, qlistwidget

I am trying to sort the file names using qtsringlist(). However, I am not sure about how to use normalsorting in QT. The outputs give me something like

"image1.png"
"image10.png"
"image100.png"

instead of "image1.png" follows by "image2.png" and so on. Then, I add the list into the list widget. Below I have attached my code.
QStringList faList; (initialized at header file)

Please help. Thanks.

```
void QtWidgetsApplication::displayImagesList() {
    QListWidgetItem *item = new QListWidgetItem();
    QDirIterator it(QStringLiteral("C:\\Users\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2015\\Projects\\cas\\images"),
        QStringList() << "*.png", QDir::Files, QDirIterator::Subdirectories);
    QFileInfo files;
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        QFileInfo file(it.next());
        faList.append(file.fileName());
        
        ui.images->setSortingEnabled(true);
    
        //ui.images->sortItems(Qt::AscendingOrder);
        _files.push_back(file.fileName());

        //cout << file.fileName().toStdString() << "\n";
        //Cout << file.fileName().length() << "\n";


        //if (file.fileName().length() == 17) {
        //  cout << file.fileName().toStdString() << "\n";
        //  
        //}

    }
    ui.images->addItems(faList);
    ui.images->setMinimumWidth(ui.images->sizeHintForColumn(0));
}
```

Comment: This question's shown code fails to meet Stackoverflow's requirements for showing a [mre]. Because of that it's unlikely that anyone here can conclusively answer the question; but only guess at the most. You need to [edit] your question to show a minimal example, no more than one or two pages of code (the "minimal" part), that everyone else can cut/paste ***exactly as shown***, compile, run, and reproduce the described issue (the "reproducible" part, this includes any ancillary information, like any input to the program). See [ask] for more information.

Comment: Please note that the rest of the codes are not related to the questions being asked :) ui.images is the listwidget drawn in ui and faList is the QStringlist

Answer (score 1):

If you need the items to be sorted in 'natural' order you can use [`QCollator`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcollator.html) and make use of its [numeric mode](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcollator.html).

Example code (untested)...

```
auto strings = QStringList{}
  << "image_3.png"
  << "image_1.png"
  << "image_4.png"
  << "image_7.png"
  << "image_2.png"
  << "image_10.png"
  << "image_5.png"
  << "image_0.png"
  << "image_8.png"
  << "image_6.png"
  << "image_9.png"
  ;
QCollator col;
col.setNumericMode(true);
std::sort(strings.begin(), strings.end(),
          [&](const QString &a, const QString &b)
            {
              return col.compare(a, b) < 0;
            });
```

Comment: It needs to be noted that pre-sorting conflicts with the `sortingEnabled` property that is used in the question. So that would need to be disabled to make this work.

Alternatively, instead of `QListWidget`/`QListWidgetItem`, a regular `QListView` with a custom model could be used to override the sort function: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qabstractitemmodel.html#sort

Comment: thanks for your answer. By the way I have more than 200 images..what should i do? can i use any loop to display those in qtsringlist? please help to show some examples..thanks

Answer (score -2):

You can't sort strings based on some numeric suffix they have.

The easiest way is to rename your images so that numeric part is zero-padded: `image001.png`, ... `image100.png` then the regular sort will work.

Alternatively, you can provide your own compare function that will parse the file name into text part and numeric part and compare them as you like.

Comment: thanks for commenting..can you show me the way of doing natural sort instead?

Comment: I really don't like the first sentence of this answer. Yes, you can sort strings however you please. You say so in the last sentence. But not how to do it with Qt. Not a very helpful answer overall.